# How to Perform a HTTP Post "directly" in Python

Tags: python, html, post, get

I do not know much about the difference between a HTTP Get and a HTTP Post so I am hoping to get some information from those more knowledgeable then me.

I have written the following code:

```
<form action="https://na.leagueoflegends.com/user/login" method="post">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="MYACCOUNTLOGINUSERNAME">
    <input name="pass" type="password" value="PASSWORD">
    <input name="form_id" id="edit-user-login" value="user_login">
    <input class="login_button" value="Submit" type="submit" style="width:100px">            
</form>
```

When I pass my actual username and password to the form and click the submit button I will be properly logged into the website.

However, when I change method from POST to GET it returns the following: https://na.leagueoflegends.com/user/login?name=MYACCOUNTLOGINUSERNAME&pass=PASSWORD&form_id=user_login and when I click this link it does not log me in.

My question is, is it possible to do a "direct" POST via Python where I do not have to create a form but instead I can just open a URL that contains the proper parameters to log me in and POST them to the server?

Thank you in advance for your knowledge, suggestions, and/or answers.

Comment: Use the same form as above, slap in an AJAX Post when you load up this page. Have a callback which redirects you to any page within that site. Faster than writing Python backend code.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. "Faster" by what means? Response time? CPU time? Programming time?

Comment: "Faster" in terms of programming & debugging time. Unless the wheel is broken, try to reuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging in basically means receiving a cookie. After sending a POST request you get a cookie that authenticates you for future GET requests. A GET request, however, cannot authenticate you unless the server side has allowed this (it shoudld not be allowed, because it is very insecure). So the answer to your question is "no, not possible".

Inserting the cookie into the real browser is not very easy. I suggest you use `mechanize`, if you want to automate the login process and do nothing else automatically. If you want to automate other things as well look into `urllib2` or `requests` for good HTTP request APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your input it has been helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The most sophisticated library to use for this purpose is probably [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.post(... your args here ...)
```

Cf. the documentation of [requests.post](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.post).

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
import urllib2

url = 'https://na.leagueoflegends.com/user/login'
params = urllib.urlencode({
  'name': 'MYACCOUNTLOGINUSERNAME',
  'pass': 'PASSWORD',
  'form_id': 'user_login'
})
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params).read()
```

[urllib2 Tutorial](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/urllib2.shtml)

Comment: Thank you for such an informative answer. I have tried implementing what you have said. If I open up the main page to the website where I am able to login http://na.leagueoflegends.com/ and then run your code and refresh the page I am not logged in? Any ideas as to why this doesn't log me in when I refresh the page or how to get a URL from what you have given me that I can enter into the browser address bar to log me into the website? Again, thank you for all your information!

Comment: Uku Loskit is correct, you would have to insert the returned cookie into your browser of choice, and my code does not do that. I think it would be a good idea to look into his suggestions.